# Random (bullet) images for List Items in a UL?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have a ul li sidebar generated from wordpress posts. The client has used different images for the bullet for each LI. Rather then adding a separate bullet manually, is there a way to do it that it chooses from a set of say 10 options?

was thinking Jquery function? Anyone ever done this?

THanks

Comment: Can you post some CSS/HTML of what you want? Are you looking to change the CSS (using `list-style-image`) or is there an `img` tag representing the bullet?

Comment: Yes using css list-style-image, but a different image for each li that is chosen dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
/* Add the styles here, incrementing the number of each one as you go (then change
   the 3 in the jQuery addClass method so it corresponds with the number of options
   available */
li.bullet-0 { list-style-type: circle; }
li.bullet-1 { list-style-type: disc; }
li.bullet-2 { list-style-type: square; }
</style>
<Script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(){
  $('ul > li').each(function(i,e){
    $(this).addClass('bullet-'+(i%3)); // change 3 to number of styles that are above.
  });
});
</script>
```

jsFiddle link to show it being applied: http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/yxZ4m/

Comment: yep, something like that! :) Would I have to always know the total number of LI's always. They will always be changing...

Comment: It's not actually the number of _items_ but the number of options available. Once it hits the end of the list it will go back to the beginning. (e.g bullet 0, 1, 2, 0, etc.) If you'd like a different approach please let me know and I'll adjust it.

Comment: oh man, that is great! Thanks. Am assuming I can add a class to specify the "ul", like "Ul.tips"

Comment: Yes, the selector doesn't matter. And you don't have to limit it to direct children (as I have). It will apply to any li you can select (though only works when they're selected as a group, otherwise a single-li selection will always apply the first style (bullet-0).

Comment: Thanks a bunch! you make it look easy (it probably is for you ;)